Counterexample Construction and Translation in CEGAR
As in this slide,

M2 is an abstraction of M1 using the abstraction function f1 which essentially groups based on labels. Then we see that the property is not satisfied by the abstraction so we find counterexamples and it says counterexample c2 is not spurious meaning it is also a counterexample for M1 after translation. My question is how is this translation done, I couldn't find anything that tells me how to do this step.
